# Finding P, given the case below

Tags: probability

If $P(A)=0.4$ and $P(B)=0.3$ and $P(A∩B') = 0.2$ since $P(A)*P(B')$
I am aware that $P(A) - P(A∩B')$ you will get $P(A \cap B)$.

I just know this formula and don't understand why. Can anyone provide an intuitive explanation on this topic ?

Is it the case that only the intersection will remain after you (-) the possibility of $P(A∩B')$ from $(A)$ and you are left with the intersection ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $A$ is the set of elements which

- either are in $A$ *and* in $B$, i.e., in $A\cap B$;
- or are in $A$ but not in $B$ (equivalently, in $A$ and in the complement $B'$ of $B$), i.e., in $A\cap B'=A\setminus B$.

Mathematically we have the disjoint union $A=(A\cap B)\sqcup(A\cap B')$.
Thus $$P(A)=P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B').$$

Comment: **The Additive Rule:** The probability for a *union* of *disjoint events* equals the sum of the probabilities for those events.$$X\cap Y=\emptyset ~\implies~ \mathsf P(X\cup Y)=\mathsf P(X)+\mathsf P(Y)$$